# WPMU for Joomla import database records from Joomla 1.5

Tags: mysql, joomla, wpmu

I have a lot of blog post on my old Joomla 1.5.26 website and I'd like to know how to import those records to Joomla 2.5.14.

The version of WPMU on my old site is com_wpmu_2.7.1.1 and com_wordpress_v3.5_j2.5-full on my new website.

Is there a tool which I can use to automatically transfer the WPMU data from old site to the new site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and wrote email to support and got the response below:

The easiest way, assuming your site doesn't have a super large amount of WordPress Multisite blogs, is to manually recreate the multisite blogs, and then use the import/export tools to migrate the posts from your old blogs to your new blogs.

You can find the import/export tools in the WordPress dashboard under the "tools" menu.

---

You can also manually import the old database.